# Modem's GPS data is piped to wrong device

Tags: devices, tty, modem, ttyusb

I have a `SIM7100E` modem running on `4.8.0-26-generic` which specifies the following devices:

```
/dev/ttyUSB1 : NMEA port for GPS NMEA data output
/dev/ttyUSB2 : AT port for AT commands
```

Connecting to `ttyUSB2` works fine, I can turn on/off GPS engine etc. But `ttyUSB1` does not produce any output data. There does not seem to be anything wrong with the GPS, because we can do

```
$ microcom /dev/ttyUSB2
AT+CGPSINFOCFG=(1,511)
```

which is a command that configures what sort of GPS NMEA data to output. The above example means "report everything once every second". This works, but the problem is that using this command, the output gets piped to `ttyUSB2` and not `ttyUSB1`, which is perpetually empty.

I'm wondering why this happens and what configurations are necessary to get the GPS data piped to `ttyUSB1`.

[Linux manual](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/how_to_use_the_sim7100_module_in_linux-driver.pdf) and [AT command set](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/simcom_sim7100_atc_en_v0.06.pdf)

I should note that the Linux configuration steps outlined in the were based on installing a module called GobiSerial -- I suppose this is where the configuration happens, but installing GobiSerial didn't work.